# JSON post doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I have this code :

```
[WebMethod]
public List<string> pubss(string gn)
    {
        List<string> onepub = new List<string>();
        iam_dbEntities db = new iam_dbEntities();
        var message = from i in db.Public_MessageSet where 
        i.RoomSet.Room_Name == gn select i;
        foreach(var s in message)
        {
            onepub.Add(s.Sender.ToString());
        }
        return onepub;
    }
```

and this Jquery Code :

```
$('#addRoom').click(function () {
 $.ajax({     
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService.asmx/pubss",
            data: "gn=Programmers",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                alert(JSON.toString(data));
            }
    });
});
```

When I click the button I expect some alerts contains information about 
the senders but nothing showed, not a single alert.

Comment: `data` being sent is not json as your contentType implies

Comment: @charlietfl so what?

Comment: so if you intend to send json then it should be json. If you intend to send form encoded data then don't set contentType as json

Answer (score -1):

Try with the following modified code

```
$.ajax({     
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebService.asmx/pubss",
            data: "{gn:'Programmers'}",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                alert(JSON.toString(data));
            }
    });
```

Comment: this code it didn't work also, i mean i see many tutorials and i see many codes but when i try to do the same nothing happend

Comment: To Call Web service methods from script there is one line present in the .asmx file. By default it was commented. Please Un-Comment and check it once

Answer (score -1):

Is there any error in console please mention? what status code for ajax? how eve you can check below precautions:
 1. On success you can try below:

```
 data = data.hasOwnProperty("d") ? data.d : data;
```

May be d property may cause. 
 2. pass your data with JSON.stringify

```
 JSON.stringify({gn:'Programmers'})
```

3. in your ajax you have  dataType: "json", 2 times.
4. if ajax is succuss then debug you webMthod and check is it returning correct data?

Comment: i added the code of error : function (req){alert(req);} and it show error : [Object][Object]. i tried with console.log error also but nothing show up.